# how to sum several columns in r?

Tags: r

I would like sum several columns in my dataframe.
For exemple, using iris r-base

I would like, for example, to sum the columns Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, and Petal.Width

I tried `colSums`, but it did not work.

```
 df<-iris%>%
  select(-Species)%>%
  colSums([1:4])
```

Update: I tried to modify the question closer to my reality.

Comment: ``colSums(iris[,1:4])``

Comment: is possible to using `%>%` pipe operator on this?

Comment: ``iris %>% dplyr::select(1:4) %>% colSums()`` ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to do

```
colSums(iris[1:4])
```

or

```
iris[1:4] %>% colSums()
```

Other options with the `%>%` pipe are

```
iris %>% 
  select(Sepal.Length,  Sepal.Width, Petal.Length,  Petal.Width) %>% 
  colSums()
```

or using the new `across` function

```
iris %>% 
  summarise(across(1:4, sum))
```

The more verbose option, but i like to use this when adding min, max quartile, etc

```
iris %>% 
  summarise(Sepal.Length = sum(Sepal.Length),  
            Sepal.Width  = sum(Sepal.Width), 
            Petal.Length = sum(Petal.Length),  
            Petal.Width  = sum(Petal.Width))
```

Comment: how do I not add the 3rd column?

Comment: For example `iris %>%  select(-3) %>%   colSums()` or `iris %>%  select(-Species) %>%   colSums()`

Comment: `iris %>%  summarise(across(1:4, sum))` is great

Comment: I noticed that 'iris %>%  summarise(across('Sepal.Length':'Petal.Width', sum))' is also even better.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `base R`

```
sapply(iris[1:4], sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another base R trick with `aggregate`

```
> aggregate(. ~ is.na(Species), iris, sum)[-1]
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1        876.5       458.6        563.7       179.9     300
```

or (thank @akrun for comments)

```
aggregate(. ~ Species, transform(iris, Species = 1), sum)
```

Comment: @akrun Haha, yes, exactly!